# php-mysql login always displays that i have match even if i dont

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am sorry if this has been asked before but i couldn't find any solution and explanation to how to log in to an existing account in mysql using php.
So i have a login page in which you need to input an email and if the email is found in my database it will display that something was found else it will display nothing was found. The problem is that even if i enter something which doesnt exist it always says that there is a match in the emails. Please lend me a hand

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'users';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
try 
{
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $servername;dbname = $dbname",$username,$password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
   {

      if(!empty($_POST["email"]))
      {
         $email = $_POST["email"];
      }

      $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,email FROM  users.registered_users WHERE email = :email');
      $records->bindParam(':email', $email);
      $records->execute();
      $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if(count($results) == 1)
      {
         echo "We have found your email";
      }
      else
      {
         echo 'email not found<br>';
      }
   }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you please show us DB structure and HTML Code ?

Comment: post your db as well...

Comment: Please check mysql:host = $servername -> mysql:host = $host

Comment: Instead of doing `if(count($results) == 1)`, just check if results were fetched or not, so instead do `if ($results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {` -- PDO::fetch() returns a boolean `false` with no data.

Comment: @MathieuDormeval what you saying doesn't make any sense in this regard

Comment: I just try to help...

Comment: @Qirel your code worked thank you everyone for helping me.